# Angular JS 1.5 - I want to communicate between angular js components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.5, angular-component-router

I am trying to expose `deletePhoto` and `editPhoto` methods of `businessPhotos` components into `verticalGrid` component. But some how it is not accessible.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

**photo.js**

```
angular.module('business')
  .component('businessPhotos', {
    templateUrl: 'business/photos.html',
    controller: [ function() {
      var $ctrl = this;
      $ctrl.editPhoto = function(photo) {
       // code
      };

      $ctrl.deletePhoto = function(id) {
       // code
      };
    }]
  });
```

---

**photo.html**

```
<vertical-grid ng-if="$ctrl.business.provider_photos" cells="$ctrl.business.provider_photos" delete-photo="$ctrl.deletePhoto(id)" edit-photo="$ctrl.editPhoto(photo)"></vertical-grid>
```

---

**vertical-grid.js**

```
angular.module('dashboard')
  .component('verticalGrid', {
    bindings: {
      cells: '<',
      deletePhoto: '&',
      editPhoto: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: 'utils/vertical-grid.html',
    selector: 'vertical-grid',
    controller: ['$element', function($element) {

      var $ctrl = this;

      $ctrl.colGrid = [];
      var numOfCols = 4;
      var numOfCells = $ctrl.cells.length;

      $ctrl.colCssClass = 'col-xs-3';


      for (var i = 0; i < numOfCells; i++) {
        var colIndex = i % numOfCols;
        if (!$ctrl.colGrid[colIndex]) {
          $ctrl.colGrid[colIndex] = [];
        }
        $ctrl.colGrid[colIndex].push($ctrl.cells[i]);
      }
    }]
  });
```

---

**vertical-grid.html**

```
<div class="provider-photos row">
  <div class="{{$ctrl.colCssClass}}" ng-repeat="col in $ctrl.colGrid track by $index">
    <div class="photo-outer-tile" ng-repeat="cell in col track by $index">
      <div class="photo-tile">
        <img ng-src="{{cell.tile_url}}">
        <div class="photo-controls">
          <a ng-click="$ctrl.deletePhoto(cell.id)" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
          <a  href="javascript:void(0);">Crop</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To communicate between angularjs controllers you could use a `service` (or a `factory`, which is conceptually very similar).
See for example [here](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services/).
You can propagate events in real-time from a service to controllers using the [`$watch`](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2852-understanding-how-to-use-scope-watch-with-controller-as-in-angularjs.htm) concept.

A simpler way is to use inject `$rootScope` in both controllers.

Comment: This is not the proper way to work with a component architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Your components are nested. The child component can call a parent's function with `require`

Example:

```
  .component('verticalGrid', {
    require: {
      parent: '^^businessPhotos'
    },
    controller: function () {
      this.$onInit = function () {
        this.parent.editPhoto();
      };
    },
```

**$onInit** is necessary to tell tell angular to wait until the component is loaded.

**^^businessPhotos** will reference the local parent component. A single ^ is also possible.